# Vuelidate - Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuelidate

I am validating a vue form with Vuelidate and I am getting the following error when trying to edit it:

```
Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

This is my form input structure:

```html
<hp-text-input
  id="company-name"
  v-model.trim="$v.formData.companyName.$model"
  :code="$v.formData.companyName.$model"
  :v="$v.formData.companyName"
  :disabled="formData.loading"
  :labeltext="$t('components.add_address_modal.company')"
  name="company-name"
></hp-text-input>
```

This is my state:

```js
data() {
  return {
    formData: {
      country: 'Ireland',
      address: '',
      addressAdditional: '',
      addressType: '',
      city: '',
      companyName: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      zipCode: '',
    },
  }
},
```

These are my Vuelidate validations:

```js
validations() {
  return {
    formData: {
      country: {},
      address: { required, max: maxLength(32) },
      addressAdditional: { max: maxLength(32) },
      addressType: { required },
      city: { required },
      companyName: {},
      firstName: { required },
      lastName: { required },
      zipCode: { required, max: maxLength(10), zipValidate },
    },
  }
},
```

I do use a vuex store in this component but it is not even related to the form data itself.
The only thing that worked to get rid of the error for now was creating a copy of the `formData` and passing it to the form, which for me doesn't make any sense to do.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you are trying to mutate a `vuex` state. As suggested by error itself - Have you used any state in the component or passing it as prop to any component. It's not necessary that the error is by this component, it might possible you are mutating somewhere else

Comment: I once used `sort` to my `vuex` state which throws this error - I end with common understanding that `sort` mutates orginal data itself. You by mistaken doing the same thing

Comment: What's stored i `$v.`?